# Share the picture from android gallery to cordova app using cordova

Tags: android, ios, android-intent, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am able to add my cordova app in share interface, but i don't no how to bring that shared picture in my cordova application.

i used com.borismus.webintent plugin

and i am calling below code in deviceready,but no luck.

```
     function startActivity() {
        alert('start');
        window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: theFile.toURL(),
            type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
        },
        function () { alert('success');},
        function () {
            alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent.');
            console.log("Failed to open URL via Android Intent. URL: " +                      theFile.fullPath)
           }
          );
       }

    function broadcast() {
         window.plugins.webintent.sendBroadcast({
         action: 'com.dummybroadcast.action.triggerthing',
         extras: {
              'option': true
          }
         }, function (args) {
             alert(args);
         }, function (args) {
             alert(args);
       });
     }


    function getURI() {
        window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function (url) {
          if (url !== "") {
            // url is the url the intent was launched with
            alert(url);
          }
          else {
            alert('ddfsdf');
          }
        });
      }
```

My requirement is in gallery if i click on sahre icon, there my application should appear and once i select my app , i should able to get that image in my cordova app.

I am using cordova 3.4.0, android[image]

and my AndroidManifest.xml is

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Share" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.creative.share.UNIQUESTRING" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity android:name="IntentTest" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
      <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>


  <activity android:name=".BrowserActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>


    <provider android:authorities="com.creative.share.plugin.emailcomposer.attachmentprovider" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.AttachmentProvider" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I can partially answer this question. I believe that you are trying to share an image to your app, where you can process it.

At the time of writing, the plugin you mentioned has a bug in it, however you can try the following workaround: https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/issues/23

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like the following:

```xml
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="Blah" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My index.js looks like the following:

```js
window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(webintent.EXTRA_STREAM,
    function (url)
    {
        console.log('getExtra: EXTRA_STREAM');
        console.log(url);

    }, function()
    {
        console.log('getExtra: EXTRA_STREAM failed');
    });
```

I hope this is useful.

For completeness, if the fix hasn't been pulled in by the time of reading, you can manually apply the change yourself in the platforms/android/src/com/borismus/webintent directory.

The suggested fix is to alter WebIntent.java (around line 94) to the following:

```java
if (i.hasExtra(extraName)) {
    String r = i.getStringExtra(extraName);
    if (null === r) {
        r = ((Uri) i.getParcelableExtra(extraName)).toString();
    }

    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, r));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Will it work for multiple images sharing? because when I select multiple images and click on share icon, my app is getting visible but it is not giving content to app and throwing "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference" error. It is working fine for single image sharing.

Please help me.

Comment: Hey @Mr_Green, I honestly don't know. You're probably best off directing this question on the original GitHub repo: https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/issues/23